# How to validate the id_token

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Based on this article: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect, I did a sample with OpenId connect protocol.

The below link says that just receiving an id_token is not sufficient to authenticate the user; you must validate the signature and verify the claims in the id_token per your app's requirements.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code

Can anyone help me to guide with some code sample how to validate the signature and verify the claims in the id_token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenId Conenct middleware takes care of validating the id_token for you. See the "about the code" section of the sample. I am pasting here the relevant parts:

> This sample shows how to use the OpenID Connect ASP.Net OWIN
>   middleware to sign-in users from a single Azure AD tenant. The
>   middleware is initialized in the Startup.Auth.cs file, by passing it
>   the Client ID of the application and the URL of the Azure AD tenant
>   where the application is registered. The middleware then takes care
>   of:
>
> *Downloading the Azure AD metadata, finding the signing keys, and
>   finding the issuer name for the tenant.
>
> *Processing OpenID Connect sign-in responses by validating the
>   signature and issuer in an incoming JWT, extracting the user's claims,
>   and putting them on ClaimsPrincipal.Current.
>
> *Integrating with the session cookie ASP.Net OWIN middleware to
>   establish a session for the user.

Comment: Thanks Vittorio for your response. It helped a me a lot to understand in details :)